# receiving UDP data in PC that send by hardware,

Tags: delphi, udp, delphi-xe, indy10, hardware-interface

I've developed a hardware (client,src ip 192.168.01.200 :9652, des ip 192.168.01.100 :9652) that reply ARP and ICMP request from pc and send UDP frame, i can check the UDP frame , ARP and icmp reply in wireshark and all of these frames are ok but i can't receive anything in my software,

in pc side (server) i set up ip address 192.168.01.100 and i wrote delphi code  for receiving udp frame by using indy10 , and then i check On_udp_read event for receiving data but this event never occur,

sever (pc):

```
  udpserver.Active := True;
  binding:=udpserver.bindings.add;
  binding.IP:= '192.168.01.100'; // my computer IP
  binding.Port:=9652;
```

Comment: I know nothing about Delphi, but try setting it active last instead of first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the `Bindings` collection **before** you activate the server, not **after**:

```
//udpserver.Active := True;
binding := udpserver.Bindings.Add;
binding.IP := '192.168.01.100';
binding.Port := 9652;
udpserver.Active := True; // <-- move down here
```

If the `Bindings` collection is empty when you activate the server, it will create a default item that is bound to IP `0.0.0.0` (IPv4) or `::1` (IPv6) on the `TIdUDPServer.DefaultPort`, which is 0 by default.  So you would end up binding to a random OS-assigned port, unless you set the `DefaultPort` beforehand, eg:

```
udpserver.DefaultPort := 9652;
udpserver.Active := True;
```

Comment: after i shift it to the end and also disabled Antivirus and windows firewall , I could't receive UDP frame in my software again, when I check "netstat -e" or "wireshark" I can see received the udp frame, the  netstat -e  show the computer didn't receive "unknown protocols frames " but received "discards frames",

Comment: If frames are being discarded, then their destination does not match any active socket.  You might want to use netstat to also verify that your udp server IP/port is actually open and in a listening state.

Comment: I've implemented my hardware to reply only to ARP  and ICMP and make and send UDP  frame,

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is if the destination MAC on the UDP packets (`00:1e:68:4d:b7:b0`) does not match the MAC on the NIC that has IP `192.168.1.100`. Did you check that yet?  You can use `ipconfig /all` for that.

Comment: yes that's match,i can transfer udp packet between two pc, but i couldn't do that between a hardware and pc, i don't know what's the problem, maybe hardware should to reply to some packet that send by pc first, and then the connection will be established,

Comment: UDP is connection-less, there is no packet that the PC should send to the hardware to establish a connection. If the code works fine between two PCs, then the problem has to be in your hardware. Clearly it is missing/malforming something, but there is no way to diagnose that from the limited information you have provided. So this is probably not a problem for StackOverflow anymore, as it is not a coding issue (other than the `Bindings` bug I already pointed out to you). There are other areas of the StackExchange community that are better suited to networking and engineering issues.

Comment: I have a question , if a pc connect to the network in the first  the pc start to reply to some packet that receive from network  (for example arp) and initialize itself and then it will be ready to communicate in the network, or no it's possible to send only UDP packet without any reply to network,

Comment: If a PC does not have a static IP address, it can obtain an IP from the network's DHCP server. But once it has an IP, it can start receiving packets destined for that IP.

Comment: I found the problem after i check my hardware's udp packet with another same udp packet (same size),  the problem was about the size of eth packet that my hardware fill it on the udp packet, now i can get udpread event (interrupt) in my software, i don't know why this error is not indicated by wireshark ,maybe first it need to init in the wireshark's preferences,